# Can't make ./configure find tcltk while building R

Tags: make, configure, r, tcl

I am trying to build R-3.2.1 from source with support for `tcltk`, but anything I try don't work, since I get then in R:

```
> capabilities("tcltk")
tcltk
FALSE
```

I am running Debian 8, I have installed the `tcl-dev tk-dev bwidget tk-table` packages. Here is an interesting output:

```
$ ./configure --with-tcltk | grep "tcl\|tk"
checking for tclConfig.sh... no
checking for tclConfig.sh in library (sub)directories... no
checking for tkConfig.sh... no
checking for tkConfig.sh in library (sub)directories... no
checking for tcl.h... no
config.status: creating src/library/tcltk/DESCRIPTION
config.status: creating src/library/tcltk/Makefile
config.status: creating src/library/tcltk/src/Makefile
```

I don't have any `[tcl|tk]Config.sh` files indeed, but I have checked that

```
/usr/include/tcl8.6/tcl.h
/usr/include/tcl8.6/tk.h
/usr/include/tcl8.6/tcl-private/generic/tcl.h
/usr/include/tcl8.6/tk-private/generic/tk.h
/usr/lib/tcltk/
/usr/lib/tcltk/x86_64-linux-gnu/
/usr/lib/tcltk/x86_64-linux-gnu/tk8.6/
```

do exist on my system. What is still wrong?

(Here are two interesting webpages I have read :

- http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Where-is-the-tcltk-package-td3434915.html
- https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-admin.html#Tcl_002fTk

)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably need to point the `configure` script at your configuration scripts:

```
./configure --with-tcltk --with-tcl-config=/usr/lib/tclConfig.sh --with-tk-config=/usr/lib/tkConfig.sh
```

These are provided respectively by `tcl-dev` and `tk-dev` in Debian 8.

Comment: This is what I've missed. I hadn't found those two files, but I might had forgotten to `updatedb` after having installing `tcl-dev tk-dev`. Thank you!